# Deserializing ArrayList.

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, arraylist

so I have an ArrayList of items and I want to send it from the server I have to the client.

This actually works 100% apart from the fact that it's being returned like this(student is my class that `implements serializable`).

```
 myPackage.student@4554617c
```

How do i deserialize this on the client? Do I create a new arraylist and then pass in the object to that?

**Relevant Server code:**

```
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    int num = din.readInt();

    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    //get details is where im getting the arraylist from.
    out.writeObject (data.getDetails(num));
```

**Relevant Client code:**

```
    //Get user input to select array element
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    out.writeInt(num);

    //get the data from the server
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    //Print the object we've got from the server
    Object test = objectInput.readObject();
    System.out.println(test);
```

I have googled and googled but I honestly have no clue what I am supposed. I *know* the client side isn't right, and that I can't just print the object. But I'm not sure what way to go about it.

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It's de-serializing correctly, override `toString` in the `class`.

Comment: Do I override in the class where I am implementing serializable?

Comment: Maybe. Override `toString` in `myPackage.student`